# compare table a and table b and update the mismatch records in table a from table b - mysql

Tags: mysql

I have table a and table b and would like to update table a from table b for any values mismatched. If there is new record in table b we can do insert in table a. I have col1 and col2 as primary keys and 13 more cols.
 If the entire record matches we can ignore the update or insert.

Appreciate help on this -

table a

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
100 aaa bbb null
200 ccc ddd eee
300 fff null    kkk
```

table b

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
100 aaa ccc ddd
200 ccc ddd eee
300 ddd kkk mmm
400 nnn ppp www
```

output  should be -

table a

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
100 aaa ccc ddd
200 ccc ddd eee
300 ddd kkk mmm
400 nnn ppp www
```

Answer (score 1):

```
REPLACE INTO table_a
SELECT * FROM table_b;
```